# OpenCart - View alternate product template based on arbitrary product field

Tags: php, templates, opencart

There is another post on Stack Overflow that includes the following code for serving multiple product templates based on product ID

```
//42 is the id of the product
if ($this->request->get['product_id'] == 42) {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/customproduct.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
    }
} else {
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/product/customproduct.tpl';
    }
}
```

I would like to check for an alternate product field value that I won't be using instead of ID so it is something that can be managed from the admin panel.

For example, a statement that reads "If product location = accessory then get product/accessory.tpl"

Would I have to load that field in the product controller before I can request it with the if statement?

What would the syntax look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any of the fields in product data in the admin panel such as Location that you already referenced.

Everything from the `product` table for your requested row should be present in the `$product_info` array.

Try something like this:

```
$template = ($product_info['location'] == 'accessory') ? 'accessory.tpl' : 'product.tpl';

if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/' . $template)) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/' . $template;
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/product/' . $template;
}
```

If you anticipate there will be many different templates for different locations it would be more efficient to use a switch control.

```
switch ($product_info['location']):
    case 'accessory':
        $template = 'accessory.tpl';
        break;
    case 'tool':
        $template = 'tool.tpl';
        break;
    default:
        $template = 'product.tpl';
        break;
endswitch;

if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/' . $template)) {
    $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/' . $template;
} else {
    $this->template = 'default/template/product/' . $template;
}
```

Hope that helps.